# Dynamically create variables in foreach loop and use on another page

Tags: php, loops, dynamic, foreach, session-variables

I'm using a dynamic template for a custom made CMS. I want to get `variables`from one php-page and, for each created site that uses that page, I want to use the variables in a `foreach` to, for example display each title.

I have made a simple example below to explain this:

```
home.com/gallery/1
home.com/gallery/2
home.com/gallery/3
```

What I get:

```
Gallery 1
Gallery 1
Gallery 1
```

What I want:

```
Gallery 1
Gallery 2
Gallery 3
```

(Assuming that each page was named Gallery 1, 2, 3)

gallery.php

```
<form action="">
        <input type="text" name="page_title"> 
</form>   
    <?php
    $galleries = array();

        $id = intval($_POST["id"]);

        ? foreach ($galleries as $id => $gallery) {
           $title = $_POST["page_title"];
        }
        $_SESSION['galleries'] =  $galleries;
        $_SESSION['title'] =  $title;
    ?>
        <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
```

page.php:

```
    $galleries = $_SESSION['galleries'];
    $title = $_SESSION['title'];

    foreach ($galleries as $id => $gallery) {                                                                                                                           
    echo $title;
    echo "<br>";
    }


    ?>
```

Note: because I want to use the variables on multiple pages I can't assign the form's action to a specific php-page.

Comment: Sidenote: Why the `?` in `? foreach`? Or, is that intended as "what should I put here"?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing. In `page.php`, why are you setting the session variables back to the same variables you got from them? Where does the content of `$_SESSION['galleries']` originally come from? And why doesn't `gallery.php` use the session variable?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, in the foreach I guess a dynamic variable should be created, so I can call that variable in the `page.php` page.
@Barmar Sorry, that was a typo! I made an edit.

Comment: fyi, you're using `$_POST` while your form is using `$_GET`

Comment: So I should change it to $_GET?
And does this aply to all forms, or only certain?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found the sollution:
page.php:

```
$galleries = $_SESSION['galleries'];
$title = $_SESSION['title'];

foreach ($galleries as $id => $gallery) {                                                                                                                           
echo $gallery["title"]; //echo this line instead of $title
echo "<br>";
}


?>
```